poisson blending / seamless cloning a head onto a body
I'm trying to paste an image of a human head onto an image of a human body and blend the two together using openCV's seamlessClone (poisson blending).  However, the head ends up taking on the color of the surrounding background (green screen) instead of just the neck.  I've also tried with a transparent background, but then it becomes very dark.  I've also tried in both mixed and normal mode.
Source image (head): https://ibb.co/Lv9P5Qp
Source image mask: https://ibb.co/b7bgwSK
Destination image (body): https://ibb.co/vcC66sr
Destination image (body, transparent background): https://ibb.co/pRZMNf1
example of issue (green background): https://ibb.co/PCyLkKG
example of issue (transparent background): https://ibb.co/Lk4cYmd
source_image = cv2.imread(source_image_path)
destination = cv2.cvtColor(headless_destination_image), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
blended = cv2.seamlessClone(source_image, destination, source_image_mask, center, cv2.NORMAL_CLONE)
cv2.imwrite('result.png', blended)

Is there any way to tell openCV to only match the color in one direction (ie the neck region, instead of all around)?

It does not appear that your source image has the same scale as your mask. As far as I know seamless cloning blends with the surrounding region and I have not seen anything in the literature to constrain it to one side. See for example https://www.cs.jhu.edu/~misha/Fall07/Papers/Perez03.pdf

Perhaps blend your face into another face with seamless cloning, not into a white background outside the face.

[mre] please. there's a bit of code missing that we'd have to fill in, and if the issue is in there, that'd be unfortunate.
